# Mongoid validation uniqueness with scope and belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, mongoid

I have the following mongoid model, with a scoped validation to prevent multiple votes on one bill. Each vote belongs to a user and a group:

```
class Vote
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :value, :type => Symbol # can be :aye, :nay, :abstain
  field :type, :type => Symbol  # TODO can delete?

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :polco_group

  embedded_in :bill
  validates_uniqueness_of :value, :scope => [:polco_group_id, :user_id, :type]

end
```

The user has the following method to add a vote to a bill:

```
  def vote_on(bill, value)    
    if my_groups = self.polco_groups # test to make sure the user is a member of a group
      my_groups.each do |g|
          # TODO see if already voted
          bill.votes.create(:value => value, :user_id => self.id, :polco_group_id => g.id, :type => g.type)
      end
    else
      raise "no polco_groups for this user" # #{self.full_name}"
    end
  end
```

and a Bill class which embeds many :votes. This is designed to allow a user to associate their vote with different groups ("Ruby Coders", "Women", etc.) and is working well, except the database currently allows a user to vote multiple times on one bill. How can I get the following to work?

```
u = User.last
b = Bill.last
u.vote_on(b,:nay)
u.vote_on(b,:nay) -> should return a validation error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably validators on `Vote` are not getting fired. You can confirm that by adding a validates function and outputting something or raising an exception in it.

```
class Vote
  validate :dummy_validator_to_confirmation

  def dummy_validator_to_confirmation
    raise "What the hell, it is being called, then why my validations are not working?"
  end
end
```

If after creating above validations `User#vote_on` doesn't raises exception, it confirms that callbacks are not fired for `Vote` via `vote_on` method. You need to change your code to fire callbacks on `Vote`. Probably changing it to resemble following would help:

```
def vote_on(bill, value)    
  if my_groups = self.polco_groups # test to make sure the user is a member of a group
    my_groups.each do |g|
        # TODO see if already voted
        vote = bill.votes.new(:value => value, :user_id => self.id, :polco_group_id => g.id, :type => g.type)
        vote.save
    end
  else
    raise "no polco_groups for this user" # #{self.full_name}"
  end
end
```

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/pull/1058) on mongoid github issue tracker to allow cascade callbacks to embedded documents. Right now callbacks are only fired on document on which persistence actions are taking place on.

Comment: I tried what you said, but got /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/activemodel-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:87:in `validates': You need to supply at least one validation (ArgumentError)

Comment: In reading the docs, I can't find a custom validator without monkeypatching. If i use a validates_presence_of, that validator does fire and work correctly.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo, `validates` should have been `validate`. On looking at the document definition again, I noticed that `Vote` is embedded in `Bill` and it might be related to that. If the presence validator is firing correctly, uniqueness would also get fired. Can you post the queries fired on mongodb when you create the new record?

Comment: Yep -- i'll post the resolution as a new answer if there is interest

Comment: @bonhoffer Can you post your resolution?  I'm experiencing a similar problem and I can't find any info elsewhere.

Comment: Please post your resolution, @bonhoffer